# use knex to dynamically create join table

Tags: javascript, postgresql, seed, knex.js

I'm learning knex right now and trying to dynamically insert the id numbers from two different tables into the empty table that will be used as a join table later on.

This is what I have so far, but I feel I'm way off base at the moment.

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex('future_join_table').del()
      .then(function () {
        return Promise.all([
        // Inserts seed entries
        knex('future_join_table').insert({
          first_id: knex('table1').select('id'),
          second_id: knex('table2').select('id')
        })
      ]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.seed = (knex) => {
  let table1Array = [];
  const toBeInsertRows = []
  return knex('future_join_table').del()
  .then(() => knex.select('id').from('table1'))
  .then((rows) => {
    table1Array = rows;
    return knex.select('id').from('table2')
  })
  .then((rows) => {
    rows.forEach((row, index) => toBeInsertRows.push({ first_id: table1Array[index].id, second_id: row.id }))
    return knex('future_join_table').insert(toBeInsertRows);
  });
}
```

The code above assume your `table1` and `table2` have same number of item.

I don't know why would you make a middle table in this way, but so far we can't perform any join operation base on your information.